# Get BindingTarget in nested MvxDialogViewController in MvxCollectionViewCell

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a `ViewModel` called `LocationsViewModel`, in which I have a `ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>`. Additionally I have a `LocationsView`, which is an `MvxCollectionViewController`, in which I create a binding set and bind a `MvxCollectionViewSource` to the `ObservableCollection`.

In the `LocationCell`, which is a `MvxCollectionViewCell`, I want to display a `MonoTouch.Dialog` which is bound to various properties in the currently
selected `LocationViewModel`. The easiest way seems to be to create a nested `MvxDialogViewController` in the `MvxCollectionViewCell`, however to bind the
`Elements` in the `MvxDialogViewController`, I obviously need to create a Binding Target. My question is really can I pass a binding target from the `MvxCollectionViewCell` to the `MvxDialogViewController`?

Let me also try to explain it briefly with some code to improve the understanding.

**LocationsViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class LocationsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations
    {
        get { return _locationDataService.Locations.Locations; }
    }
    ...
}
```

**LocationViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class LocationViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    //Tons of public properties like:
    public string Name
    {
        get { return LinkedDataModel.Name; }
        set
        {
            LinkedDataModel.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public double CurrentNoiseLevel
    {
        get { return LinkedDataModel.CurrentNoiseLevel; }
        set
        {
            LinkedDataModel.CurrentNoiseLevel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentNoiseLevel);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**LocationsView.cs**

```cs
[Register("LocationView")]
public class LocationsView
    : MvxCollectionViewController
{
    static readonly NSString LocationCellId = new NSString("LocationCell");
    private readonly bool _isInitialized;

    public LocationsView()
        : base(new UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        {
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0f,
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal,
            MinimumLineSpacing = 0f
        })
    {
        _isInitialized = true;
        ViewDidLoad();
    }

    public new LocationsViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (LocationsViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public sealed override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
            return;

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(LocationCell), LocationCellId);
        var source = new MvxCollectionViewSource(CollectionView, LocationCellId);
        CollectionView.Source = source;
        CollectionView.PagingEnabled = true;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LocationsView, LocationsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Locations);
        set.Apply();

        CollectionView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

**LocationCell.cs**

```cs
public class LocationCell : MvxCollectionViewCell
{
    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public LocationCell(RectangleF frame)
        : base(string.Empty, frame)
    {
        InitView();
    }

    public LocationCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(string.Empty, handle)
    {
        InitView();
    }

    private void InitView()
    {
        var cell = new LocationCellDialog();
        ContentView.Add(cell.View);
    }

    public class LocationCellDialog 
        : MvxDialogViewController
    {
        public LocationCellDialog() 
            : base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null, true) 
        { }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //How do I get the target here?
            var target = ??;
            Root = new RootElement
            {
                new Section
                {
                    new StringElement().Bind(target, t => t.Name),
                    new StringElement().Bind(target, t => t.CurrentNoiseLevel)
                }.Bind(target, t => t.Name),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is can I simply pass along a binding target from the parent LocationCell to nested LocationCellDialog or is that a no go?

Answer (score 2):

Each `bindable view` in MvvmCross has its own `DataContext`

For a top level `View` this `DataContext` is the `ViewModel`

For a `Cell` within a `List`, `Table` or `Collection` then the `DataContext` is set to the object in the list which the `Cell` is currently showing.

If you want to data-bind any property within a `Cell` to a property path on the `DataContext` then you can do so using the Fluent binding syntax.

For example, to bind the `Text` value of a child `UILabel` called `myLabel` to a child property `Name` on a `Person` in the list you could use:

```
 this.CreateBinding(myLabel).For(label => label.Text).To<Person>(p => p.Name).Apply();
```

Or if you wanted to bind the `Text` to the `Person` itself you could use:

```
 this.CreateBinding(myLabel).For(label => label.Text).Apply();
```

---

In your `LocationCell` I think you are saying you want to bind the `DataContext` of the nested `LocationCellDialog` to the `DataContext` of the containing cell.

To do this you should be able to use:

```
private void InitView()
{
    var cell = new LocationCellDialog();
    ContentView.Add(cell.View);
    this.CreateBinding(cell).For(cell => cell.DataContext).Apply();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will look at it soon :)

Comment: OK, I think it works now, however using `var target = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<LocationViewModel>()` does not work when binding an `Element` in the `MvxDialogViewController` like: `new StringElement().Bind(target, t => t.Name);` while `new StringElement().Bind(this, "Value Name");` does while also having a `ViewModel` property defined in the `MvxDialogViewController`. Upon inspecting the result of the `CreateInlineBindingTarget` the `ViewModel` is null because of an cast error. Any idea why this is?

Comment: What's the cast error? Casting from what to what? (Kind of hard to read this in comments too... Sorry, but not sure this is an issue yet)

Comment: It gets cut off for some reason. I can test next week when I am at work again. From the top of my head it said it could not cast LocationViewModel to and then it was cut off with ... Will get back!